# How to write WEBPAGE HTML table in xlsx sheet?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I have a webpage and inside that page there is a table.
Now i have to print this table in .xlsx sheet.
Please suggest how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write loop for getting all the table values into excel sheet. below is the code which i tried in my project.

```
public void getWebTableValues() throws Exception
{
    WebElement data1=d.findElement(By.xpath("xpath of table"));
    List<WebElement> tableRows = data1.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
    int rowSize=tableRows.size();
    System.out.println(rowSize);
    fis1=new FileInputStream("path of the excel sheet upto ExcelSheet.xlsx");
    wb1=new XSSFWorkbook(fis1);
    st1=wb1.getSheetAt(1);
    for (int i=0; i<rowSize; i++) 
    {
        WebElement webRow = tableRows.get(i);
        //Get all cell values in each row
        List<WebElement> allCells = webRow.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
        //System.out.println(allCells.size());
        if(allCells.size() > 1)
        {
            row = st1.createRow(i);
            for (int j=0; j<allCells.size(); j++)
            {
                WebElement webCell = allCells.get(j);
                String text = webCell.getText();
                if(text.length()>3)
                {
                    cell = row.createCell(j);
                    cell.setCellValue(webCell.getText());
                }
                FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("path of the excel sheet upto kpmgExcelSheet.xlsx");
                wb1.write(fos); 
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps you